# Advice needed in debugging JAXB / JBOSS behaviour

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jaxb

I am using Spring WebServiceTemplate.marshallSendAndReceive() to communicate with a Web Service.

If I run my code outside of an application server, it works correctly. If I run it *inside* my Application Server ( JBOSS EPP ) the marshalling produces markedly different results.

The expected XML looks something like

```
<root>
   <element1/>
</root>
```

When I run in the AppServer I get something like

```
<root/>
```

That is, my child element is not created and attached to my root element.

I'm assuming that this is related to JAXB, but when I debug the code, my JAXBContext appears to come from the same jar file both in the app server and outside it.

Are there any other dependencies I need to be aware of and can influence?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1):

My co-workers had some troubles with JAXB in past. This troubles were based on different XML parser implementation in different runtime environment. In our case some environment had xerxes parser, which lead to some error in case of concurrent execution. You can try to find out which xml parser is used by your application and change it if it differs. I hope this info will be useful for you.